# Setting compound properties thru a form. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I set compound `Address` (contains *street*, *city* etc.) property on my model on a form?

Should it be some kind of helper?

**View**

```
@model Person

@using(@Html.BeginForm("Create", "Person", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()    
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            @Html.Label("MiddleName") <br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.MiddleName)
        <p>

        @* And so on... *@

        @* What about Model.Address ? How do I assign person's `Address` properties? *@

    </fieldset>
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // the default model binder will take care of populating
        // your view model along with its complex properties
        ...
    }

}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address.Street)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address.Street)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address.City)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address.City)
    </div>

    <p><button type="submit">OK</button></p>
}
```

Comment: Ok. I undersatnd that. But I'm using a *strongly-typed* view (depending on `Person`) and trying to assign to its model (atomary) properties. `Address` isn't atomary.. So howcome I do this on the same form? I'm not sure but probably it's not supported to use several models on a view?

Comment: @helicera, I don't understand what you said. Maybe you could exemplify your problem with a code?

Comment: @helicera, I have looked at your update. Why can't you use `@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Address.City)`?

Comment: Oops.. I had a typo so when I was accessing the inner properties it gave an error. Thanks!